# TypeError: push() is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to push an item to an array but it's not working. When I run the code, I get this error:

> --Uncaught TypeError: data.allItems[type].push is not a function--

```
var data = {
    allItems: {
      exp: [],
      inc: []
    },
    totals: {
      exp: 0,
      inc: 0
    },
    budget: 0,
    percentage: -1
  };

  return {
      addItem: function(type, des, val) {
          var newItem, ID;

          // Create new ID
          if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {
              ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
          } else {
              ID = 0;
          }

          // Create new item based on 'inc' or 'exp' type
          if (type === 'exp') {
              newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
          } else if (type === 'inc') {
              newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
          }

          // Push it into our data structure
          data.allItems[type].push(newItem);

          // Return the new element
          return newItem;
      },
```

Comment: can you add the output of `console.log(type)` right before you `push` ?

Comment: This might make it easier for others to help: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/35899)

Comment: In addition to @Taki's comment, what does `console.log((typeof type));` return? Is it possible that `type` is treated as a keyword/reserved word by the JS engine?

Comment: Is this an assignment from a school or online coding site? There are several questions with the exact same code on SO https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=exp+inc+allItems&mixed=0

Answer (score 4):

You need to first check if your desired array is present in your object. If so, then push to it.

```
if(data.allItems[type] && Array.isArray(data.allItems[type])) {
    data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
} else {
  console.warn(type + " is undefined in `allItems`!");
}

// OR

if (data.allItems[type] == undefined || !Array.isArray(data.allItems[type])) {
  // Your Error handler
}
```

> Notice: You can only perform `push()` and `pop()` methods on an array.

```js
const finalArray = {};
finalArray.push({ id: 1}) // You will definitely get an error.
```

Comment: This additional validation won't solve anything if OP is sending `type` to be something other than `"exp"` and `"inc"`

Comment: Completely aggry..and even It's not  `exp` or `inc` then just throw an appropriate error or put a new key  based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

data.allItems[type] - is undefined in your case , you can use `push` only for Arrays.

Comment: If `data.allItems[type]` is undefined, it would throw  *"Cannot read property 'push' of undefined*"

Comment: if it was `undefined` you'd get `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: This answer doesn't suggest a fix, which isn't helpful to new users.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly referencing the array to which you are trying to push.

I would look at writing an `if` statement to reference the array to which you want to push and then pass an argument to the function call.

```
var data = {
    allItems: {
      exp: [],
      inc: []
    },
    totals: {
      exp: 0,
      inc: 0
    },
    budget: 0,
    percentage: -1
  };

function hi(type) {
  var test;
  if (type === "exp") {
       test = data.allItems.exp;
      } else {
       test = data.allItems.inc;
  }

  test.push('hi');
  console.log(test);

}

hi('exp');
```